# Laravel routes collision

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to build a simple CRUD app and I am facing some issues regarding routes. For viewing a group i have the following route

```
Route::get('/groups/{id}','GroupsController@show');
```

and for creating

```
Route::get('/groups/create','GroupsController@create')->name("groups.create");
```

issue is that with above routes defined `create` module is not working but when i comment out the `/routes/{id}` route it does.

Any help in solving this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on the order that you define them, so put the create route before the wild card route and you will be fine.

Comment: glad it helped. Please consider accepting the answer :) happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

- First of all you should not do any creating via `GET` request. Better to use `POST` instead.
- Second - it's ordering, because `{id}` - is any string in your case. (`create` - is also string...) So you can move `create` route before of `{id}`.
- Third - add clarification for id if it's only numeric, like `Route::get('/groups/create','GroupsController@create')->name("groups.create")->where(['id' => '[0-9]+');`

Any of this solution can solve you problem. But better to change all of this.

Comment: From a resourceful controller the `create` is always `get` method as it only loads the view, `store` is `post` which stores the resource to the data store.

Comment: Yep. You right. I meant creating an entity when talking about `create`